# Am I trying to do something that can't be done this way?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've created a website for image uploads and now I'm trying to implement tagging system. When uploading an image, you pick the tag you want to use from a html select tag and then the info about the image is POST-ed to my file that deals with the logic behind the upload. Now since I want my image to be able to have more than one tag, I'm using 3 tables set up like this :

```
Table: image
Columns: id, title, description, author, date, path

Table: tags
Columns: id, tag

Table: tagsconnection
Columns: imageid, tagid
```

My MySQL queries are the following :

```
$userSearch = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$author'";
                    $userResult = mysqli_query($conn, $userSearch);
                    $authorCheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userResult);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO image (id, name, description, author, date, path) 
                    VALUES (NULL, '".$name."','".$description."','".$authorCheck['username']."','".$date."','".$fileNameNew."')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE name='$name'";
                    $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                    $imageIdCheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2);
                    $imageid = $imageIdCheck['id'];

                    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag='$tag'";
                    $sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
                    $tagCheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3);
                    $tagid = $tagCheck['id'];

                    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO tagsconnection (id, imageid, tagid) VALUE (NULL, '".$imageid."', '".$tagid."')";
                    $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
```

This way, my image table is getting successfully populated with the image info, however, my tagsconnection table only receives the id of the tag BUT doesn't receives the id of the uploaded image. Obviously I can't know the id of the image before it gets uploaded so that's why my image tag query is after the image info input query. In my tagsconnection table, the imageid is always 0.

Comment: You're explicitly inserting `NULL` into all of the `id` columns.  Shouldn't those be auto-generated IDs instead?  Then you can use `mysqli_insert_id` to get the generated ID.

Comment: i dom't see code for assign proper values  to  $imageid and $tagid

Comment: The NULL part doesn't seem to be the problem since I'm getting the correct tagid input into the tagsconnection table, however, the imageid is not getting correctly input. If the problem were the NULL, wouldn't they both not get input correctly?

Comment: Do you mean that you're *not* getting the value you need for `$imageid`? If so, what does `var_dump($imageIdCheck)` give you? Note that in your `$sql2` query you're filtering by `name` which doesn't exist in the columns you listed above.

Comment: Oh wow, that is a huge mistake on my part. Thanks Optimae, now it's working like a charm.